# Hide Soft Keyboard When User Touches the Dropdown Menu

Tags: android, kotlin, autocompletetextview, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout

I have the following Android Material Components exposed drop-down menu in my app:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/drop_down_menu"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar"
    app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/number_text_view"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/add_button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/number_text_view">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="none"
        android:paddingStart="8dp"
        android:paddingEnd="8dp" />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

How do I hide the soft keyboard in my fragment when the user touches the drop-down menu and the menu options appear? The keyboard shows when the user clicks on the `EditText` component and doesn't touch another part of the screen before touching the drop-down menu to close the keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register `focusChangeListener` to the `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView` and hide the keyboard when it gained the focus.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus) {
        hideSoftKeyboard() // Using activity extension function
        // v.hideKeyboard() // Using view extension function
    }
}
```

And here is Activity extension function to hide the keyboard:

```
fun Activity.hideSoftKeyboard() {
    val inputMethodManager =
        this.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    val currentFocus = this.currentFocus
    val windowToken = this.window?.decorView?.rootView?.windowToken
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
        windowToken,
        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS
    )
    if (currentFocus != null) {
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(currentFocus.windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Or you can use the below on the `View` itself.
[Source](http://kotlinextensions.com/)

```
fun View.hideKeyboard(): Boolean {
    try {
        val inputMethodManager = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        return inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    } catch (ignored: RuntimeException) { }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: The soft keyboard still shows even after touching the drop-down menu. I don't want the keyboard overlapping the menu options when they are exposed, which is why I want the menu to disappear once the user touches the menu. Why are we checking the `actionBar` when we're supposed to be checking the `TextInputLayout` or `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`? And why is `Activity` being used for both the `onResume` and `hideSoftKeyboard` functions when this is all happening in a `Fragment`?

Comment: You need to intercept an action on the `actionbar` options menu to hide the keyboard. So, why you are supposed to check TextInputLayout or MaterialAutoCompleteTextView? .. Activity is used because you probably need to use this in more than one fragment, so you would repeat yourself. The other reason `getSystemService` can't be called on a fragment

Comment: So should I move the code to my `Activity` that is hosting the fragments? Because if I can't use `getSystemService` then what am I supposed to do?

Comment: `onResume()` here is a part of the fragment not activity.. `Activity.hideSoftKeyboard()` is an extension function that you can put anywhere in your app

Comment: @TomDarious Please check UPDATE section in the answer

Comment: What is `myEditText` supposed to be? The `TextInputLayout` or `MaterialAutoCompleteTextView`?

Comment: The `EditText` component you referred to in the question which triggers the Keyboard

Comment: Well there's a total of two `EditText` components in my app. I tried using the `hideKeyboard` function on both components, but it still showed even after touching the drop-down menu. I want the keyboard to automatically close the second the user touches the drop-down menu and the menu options appear.

Comment: @TomDarious There is something missing that I couldn't reproduce the issue; the keyboard hides in mine .. If you would like to create a demo app; so we can test on and try to find the problem

Comment: Did you use the exact same xml code I have above? And was yours `EditText` or `AppCompatEditText`? Because mine is the `AppCompatEditText` so I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: @TomDarious Excuse me as it was misunderstood; I totally changed the approach .. please have a look

Comment: This worked, thank you so much for all of your responses.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bindingSheet.dropDownFloorList.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            hideSoftKeyboard() // Using activity extension function
            // v.hideKeyboard() // Using view extension function
        }
    }
```